# Filter unwanted terms

Tags: nlp, text-mining

I have the following keywords retrieved from a text document.

```
natural language processing
sequential labeling 
programmable
spell checking
techniques
forensics 
important issue 
categorial grammar
girls
applications
```

Now I want to remove unwanted words such as `programmable, techniques, important issue, girls, applications` from this keyword list. Is there a way to automate this? Can I consider some pos-tag pattern to do this?

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for. There are many ways to do this. One simple way is like this,

```
word_list = ['natural language processing', 'sequential labeling', 'programmable', 'spell checking', 'techniques', 'forensics', 'important issue', 'categorial grammar', 'girls', 'applications']
```

Since you said, a list of key words,

```
stopwords = ['programmable','techniques', 'important issue', 'girls', 'applications']

resultwords  = [word for word in word_list if word.lower() not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)

print (result)
```

This will yield,

```
>> natural language processing sequential labeling spell checking forensics categorial grammar
```

Otherwise, if you just have a string of text, use `split()` method to put each word into a list splitting by space.

```
querywords = word_list.split()

resultwords  = [word for word in querywords  if word.lower() not in stopwords]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)
```

You can always warp them into a function and automate this. As I said there are many ways to do it, without knowing what have you tried, this is a simple way to do without using `nltk` library.